# Secondary monitor not connecting in 18.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 18.04, external-monitor

I have an Acer Aspire V Nitro VN7-592G-709V with Nvidia Geforce 960M (nvidia driver v390) and a Benq W1070 projector.

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and my projector connects for a split second and then gets disconnected. In Ubuntu 16.04 projector was working fine as a mirror display and extended desktop. Here's what I already tried:

- enable the nouveau driver instead of the nvidia driver -> no result
- enable the on-board intel board with sudo prime-select intel -> no result
- apt purge nvidia* & reinstall nvidia driver 390 (stable) or 396 (beta) -> no result
- disable nouveau driver, disable nvidia driver from the repository and install nvidia driver from nvidia website (both 390 and 396) -> no result
- installed CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) and disabled display auto-detection -> no result
- played around with the refresh rate (some forums say that the two outputs have to be in sync -> no result
- deleted the whole Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade and installed a fresh 18.04 -> still the same issue
- tried to manually enable the output with xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --mode 1920x1920 -> nothing
- under settings -> devices -> displays I don't see a secondary display (just the main one)

Here is the output of xrandr the very second when I connect the projector (then HDMI-1-2 goes disconnected and no modes are displayed):

```
    ~$ xrandr
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
    eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
       1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93
       1680x1050     59.95    59.88
       1600x1024     60.17
       1400x1050     59.98
       1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
       1280x1024     60.02
       1440x900      59.89
       1400x900      59.96    59.88
       1280x960      60.00
       1440x810      60.00    59.97
       1368x768      59.88    59.85
       1360x768      59.80    59.96
       1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
       1152x864      60.00
       1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
       1024x768      60.04    60.00
       960x720       60.00
       928x696       60.05
       896x672       60.01
       1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
       960x600       59.93    60.00
       960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
       800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
       840x525       60.01    59.88
       864x486       59.92    59.57
       800x512       60.17
       700x525       59.98
       800x450       59.95    59.82
       640x512       60.02
       720x450       59.89
       700x450       59.96    59.88
       640x480       60.00    59.94
       720x405       59.51    58.99
       684x384       59.88    59.85
       680x384       59.80    59.96
       640x400       59.88    59.98
       576x432       60.06
       640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
       512x384       60.00
       512x288       60.00    59.92
       480x270       59.63    59.82
       400x300       60.32    56.34
       432x243       59.92    59.57
       320x240       60.05  
       360x202       59.51    59.13
       320x180       59.84    59.32
    DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
      1920x1080 (0x258) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0x259) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0x25a) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
      1920x1080i (0x25b) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
      1920x1080i (0x25c) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
            h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0x25d) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  30.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0x25e) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  25.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0x25f) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  27.00KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  24.00Hz
      1920x1080i (0x260) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
      1920x1080 (0x261) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  29.97Hz
      1920x1080 (0x262) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  26.97KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  23.98Hz
      1600x1200 (0x263) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
            v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
      1280x1024 (0x264) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
            v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
      1440x900 (0x265) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
            h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
            v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
      1280x800 (0x266) 146.250MHz +HSync -VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock 101.56KHz
            v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  847           clock 119.91Hz
      1152x864 (0x267) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
            v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
      1280x720 (0x268) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
      1280x720 (0x269) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
      1280x720 (0x26a) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
      1024x768 (0x26b) 115.500MHz +HSync -VSync
            h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  97.55KHz
            v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  813           clock 119.99Hz
      1024x768 (0x26c) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
            v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
      1024x768 (0x26d) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
            v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
      1024x576 (0x26e) 46.970MHz -HSync +VSync
            h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1168 total 1312 skew    0 clock  35.80KHz
            v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.97Hz
      832x624 (0x26f) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
            v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
      800x600 (0x270) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
            v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
      800x600 (0x271) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
            v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
      720x576 (0x272) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
            v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
      720x576i (0x273) 13.500MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
            h: width   720 start  732 end  795 total  864 skew    0 clock  15.62KHz
            v: height  576 start  580 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
      720x480 (0x274) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
            v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
      720x480 (0x275) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
            v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
      720x480i (0x276) 13.514MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
            h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.75KHz
            v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
      720x480i (0x277) 13.500MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
            h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.73KHz
            v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
      640x480 (0x278) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
            v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
      640x480 (0x279) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
            v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
      640x480 (0x27a) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
            v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
      640x480 (0x27b) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
            v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
      720x400 (0x27c) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
            h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
            v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
```

Anyone has any ideea where I can start debugging this?

Thanks!

Comment: Potentially the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
    xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-2 1920x1080
    xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --mode 1920x1080
```

This sequence of commands enables clone display. However, I still don't see anywhere in Displays/Monitors the secondary display.

Here is the xrandr output (while projector is on):

```
    HDMI-1-2 disconnected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
       1920x1080     60.02*
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. In my display settings my monitor was detected but seems like It had some resolution problems that I fixed with this commands. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have two graphics cards in my *Dell* Notebook, Intel and NVidia.
After updating, this problem appeared and I solved it with the following command

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```