# Ubuntu 18.10 external monitor with intel graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

I wanted to attach an external monitor through HDMI to my optimus laptop (Gigabyte Aero 15x) but it did not work. I found a solution that works for me in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/a/1094034/827960

Due to too little reputation, it is not possible to ask a question there, hence this new one.

I figured out that it only works with prime-select Nvidia and lightdm.
My question now is if there is any way to make it work with Intel GPU? It is not a huge problem as most of the time I can be plugged in, as Nvidia draws much more power, but sometimes with presentations, it would be nice to save that battery.

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if you are using G-Sync?: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/any-point-in-holding-off-on-the-gigabyte-aero-15.805248/page-6 Also in BIOS your settings might be for *Performance* which might override to use nVidia all the time?

Comment: 1. Do you know how to turn off the nvidia driver/chip? 2. What's the model name of your Intel GPU?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The short version:

Your laptop's HDMI port is wirred to the nVidia card in Hardware.  No software solution can change this, you need to resort to a mini-DP --> HDMI hardware convertor to make this work.

### TL;DR:

From: [Aero 15X v8 annoyances](https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabytegaming/comments/90jze6/aero_15x_v8_annoyances/):

> Second issue has to do with Nvidia optimus and essentially requires me
> to relog or restart the pc when I disconnect from an external display
> to keep the battery from draining running on the gtx 1070. Assuming I
> boot the PC without any external displays connected, non-game
> applications will utilize the onboard gpu as expected. If I boot the
> PC with an external display connected however, everything (web
> browsers, even windows shell) will use the dedicated gtx 1070. This
> also applies to any applications started when connecting an external
> monitor after booting. None of the applications will switch to the
> integrated gpu after disconnecting the monitor and nothing short of a
> relog/restart will solve the issue.
>
> I've tried forcing global settings in Nvidia control panel to the
> integrated gpu, updated all drivers but all to no avail.
>
> Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

In the answers section this is discovered:

> This is not the case with the Aero 15 however. It seems that the
> display outputs are wired to the GTX 1070 which forces all
> applications that were started on any display connected to the
> HDMI/mDP port to be rendered with the GTX 1070.
>
> I tested this by having the laptop's screen enabled while connected
> via mDP to an external monitor. If the built-in screen is set as
> primary, applications launched will run on the iGPU. When the external
> monitor is set as primary, all applications started will run on the
> 1070.

**Note:** My Alienware AW17R3 has the external HDMI port hardwired to the nVidia Geforce GTX970M GPU as well and I cannot use the Intel iGPU to drive the Laptops HDMI external port. The Intel iGPU will only drive the builtin display and Thunderbolt 3 USB-C port which has a DPI-->HDMI adapter ($25) to another external monitor.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer @WinEunuuchs2Unix :)
Just to make sure I understood the conclusion, sorry if it looks stupid, if I would get a cable to connect the monitor through the USB-C port it would work? That would be amazing.

Comment: I can now confirm that a Thunderbolt 3-USB-C to VGA/HDMI works with the iGPU :)

Comment: Um good? Do I need to change my answer in any way?

Comment: Now, your answer is still perfect, thank you for that. I just answered my own question because I was not sure whether it would work. Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: For future references the mini-DP is also connected to NVIDIA this might save you buying a mini DP like I did

Comment: I have the feeling this (hardwired to dedicated GPU) is the case with my laptop as well.
My laptop is  Acer NITRO5 (Inter corei7-8750H; nVidia Geforce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile). I will check the USB-C to HDMI way.

Comment: @V-Mark, did USB-C to HDMI work? I am also interested in USB-C 3.1 to DP 1.2 connection.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is not correct. 
First of all HDMI port & the mini DP are all linked to the nvidia Card. 
**Only the (thunderbolt PORT / USB C) uses INTEL CARD.**

When you're using NVIDIA YOU NEED TO USE LIGHTDM to make the external monitor work:

```
$ sudo apt install lightdm & sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then choose lightdm.
With this option audio wouldn't work! You need to use this library [hhfeuer/nvhda](https://github.com/hhfeuer/nvhda)

**NB: Only works on prime-select nvidia.**

1. git clone https://github.com/hhfeuer/nvhda
2. cd nvhda
3. make
4. sudo make install
5. echo nvhda | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
6. echo "options nvhda load_state=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/nvhda.conf
7. sudo update-initramfs -u

Comment: I have to argue with the statement: "using NVIDIA YOU NEED TO USE LIGHTDM".
My case: Acer NITRO5 (Inter corei7-8750H; nVidia Geforce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile).
OS: Kubuntu 19.04. External HDMI works from nVidia with sddm (default dm of KUbuntu).