# External monitor not detected after updating to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

After updating to version 18.04 my external monitor is not detected any longer. I have tried to follow some of the suggestions from [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04) (adding mode, installing lightdm, etc.) with no luck.
The output of `xrandr` is as follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.01  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The detailed information about the graphic card (running `sudo lshw -C video`) is as follows:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Any thoughts on how could I solve this? I have tried the same monitor with the same cable with previous versions of Ubuntu from my colleagues's laptops and there were no problems at all.

Editing as suggested:

Using a live image partially did the trick for me: I load a live image, reboot the computer extracting it, and now it does appear again. Strangely now, both screens are cloned when I logged in, but the monitor one gets black once I logging into. However, if I unplug and plug again the HDMI cable, I get the configuration I want (as joined displays, having the icons and bars in the monitor one).

Comment: Yes, it does! I removed it, reboot it again, and now it does appear again. Strangely now, both screens are cloned when I logged in, but the monitor one gets black once I logging into. However, if I unplug and plug again the HDMI cable, I get the configuration I want (as joined displays, having the icons and bars in the monitor one). It is not perfect... but it is such a progress, thanks a lot!

Comment: Done @K7AAY: I have added the partial solution to the main comment. Thanks!

Comment: Check also the "display on dock"  in the BIOS