# External monitor not connected

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, external-monitor

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 into my laptop along with windows 10. Unfortunately, my external monitor which is connected into HDMI-1 is not working on Ubuntu (Not detected). I tried almost everything [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04) and [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025530/linux/geforce-940mx-external-screen-not-detected-on-ubuntu-17-10/). It is connected with [HDMI-to-VGA_Adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Active-Adapter-Benfei-Converter-Gold-Plated/dp/B01KLKQN9U/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=hdmi%20to%20vga%20audio%20adapter&qid=1571533763&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExNVpYRjNLMkJTWEJMJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzc4ODE4Mlg2MkhSNDZMUlIyNiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNjc3ODk1MUtFOFg4VEZIMjhQMiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=). My graphics card is GeForce GTX 1650 and I tried to download [this](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us) drivers from NVidia. Also, as you can see in the picture, on screen display settings it's not even show the screen layout.

On Ubuntu 14.04 (my old laptop) I had solved similar problem in the past by using something like:

```
echo $myNewMode
## Output: "1368x768_60.00" 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 $myNewModeName
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode $myNewModeName --output HDMI-1 --auto --right-of eDP-1
```

But, this didn't work either. Any ideas ?

[image]

UPDATE: I had run `X -configure` (only main screen was working) as mention [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there) and afterwords I had run `nvidia-xconfig` (Only HDMI works). Somehow, it seems that nvidia took the most recent created file `xorg.conf.new` and made it's own `xorg.conf` from it. Still, if I unplug HDMI everything is blank. AT least now I can see one screen layout(HDMI) and contents on `nvidia x server settings` application window (it was blank before)[image]

Here is the latest `xorg.conf` file:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 440.26

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath        "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName      "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName      "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"

        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "CustomEDID"            # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "Present"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWRotation"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VSync"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # <i>
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier     "Card0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"

        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
    Identifier     "Card1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Card0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Card1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Latest `xrandr` output:
[image: xrandr]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100096/discussion-on-question-by-ioaniatr-external-monitor-not-connected).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it work on dual screen. I did many steps and is one of the solutions that makes you wonder "It works, how??". My last steps was:

1 - I enabled/selected `gdm3` instead of `lightdm` as manager:

```
sudo gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

2 - Log into recovery mode following steps [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/).

3 - Completely delete the file `rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

4 - Run `X -configure`, but NOT replace the file that was created `/root/xorg.conf.new` into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

5 - Reboot into normal mode and I was expecting something messed up, but suddenly dual monitor was active and working fine.

Currently, it works without any `xorg.conf` file.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am little bit scared to touch it right now, although that I think that I should try to re-create the `xorg.conf` file, maybe through nvidia?! I hope that this could be useful to others with similar issue.

Also, if I enable secure boot on bios goes back to zero and dual monitor is not working, although that ubuntu are running properly. Maybe, need to signed drivers into kernel or something, I am not sure.

If anyone has any idea about what actually happened, I will be happy to hear.