# Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME looks weird after changing display managers

Tags: gnome, display, themes, lightdm

When trying to solve my problem with [external monitor not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)
I followed an advice to change my display manager to lightdm. I ended up in a [login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) so I followed the advice there, uninstalled lightdm and successfully logged in. However, everything looks different now and not very pretty (see the pictures below).

[image: the terminal]

[image: folder]

I have changed my display manager to gdm3 but nothing changed. And when rebooting, I again ended up in a login loop and had to follow steps in the link above to log in again.

**Question**: What is it that I did and how can I fix it to have a normal looking GNOME environment again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your GTK theme got switched to *Adwaita*, the default GTk theme for *GNOME* (Ubuntu doesn't use this one by default, 18.04 has *Ambiance* and *Radiance*). So you just need to change your GTK theme to something you like.

To do that first install (GNOME) Tweaks by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then launch Tweaks and change the application theme in the '*Appearance*' section.