# external monitor / hdmi port not working on AMD-based system

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics, xrandr

I'm trying to dual-boot the [MSI Alpha 15](https://us.msi.com/Laptop/Alpha-15-A3DX) with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.3. Everything has worked out fine, except for my external monitor which is not working.

The MSI Alpha comes with an AMD Ryzen 7 CPU and an AMD Radeon RX GPU, this makes it different from the more common Intel/Nvidia combination.

I have tried the Nvidia-based solutions as outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04). I also installed the [AMD Radeon Software for Linux (version 19.50 for Ubuntu 18.04.3)](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux). Both approaches did not solve the problem.

In addition, my HDMI port does not show up in `xrandr`.

How can I make Ubuntu recognize my display?

Comment: May I please ask you to confirm the AMD package you downloaded and installed was _Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 19.50 for Ubuntu 18.04.3_ ? Please click [edit] and put your answer in the question, so all the info needed to solve the problem is in the question; please don't use Add Comment.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when installing Fedora 32 on a new Alpha 15. On boot, I saw messages stating

> AMD-VI Completion-Wait loop timed out.

I had to add `amd_iommu=off` to my kernel parameters.
Credit goes to [the Arch lovers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519758/amd-vi-completion-wait-loop-after-a-failed-install-of-arch-linux-on-a-blank-ssd) who solved this problem.