# display not working after Ubuntu splash screen

Tags: display, monitor

18.04 on an Asus Z97.

On boot, the monitor works fine and gets as far as displaying the Ubuntu splash screen (Ubuntu plus the dots). After that the display loses the signal. I have vino running and remote desktop works fine.

I've tried both HDMI and DVI, and both an Elecrow 1080p and an old Viewsonic monitor. Every time, the signal is lost at the same point. I've tried various screen resolutions but no difference.

From the remote desktop, display settings shows 'unknown monitor'.

I'm running gdm3 as I was never able to get lightdm running on this system. I just tried it again and it fails to create a display so I can't even get a remote desktop. I can still log in with putty though.

I tried some of the solutions here: [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04) but no luck.

With gdm3:

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1600 x 1200, maximum 1920 x 1200
default connected primary 1600x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200     60.00*   70.00    65.00
   1920x1200     60.00
   1920x1080     60.00
   1680x1050     70.00    60.00
   1400x1050     70.00    60.00
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     60.00
   1440x900      60.00
   1400x900      60.00
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00
   1368x768      60.00
   1360x768      60.00
   1280x800      60.00
   1152x864      70.00    60.00
   1280x720      60.00
   1024x768      70.00    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.00
   896x672       60.00
   1024x576      60.00
   960x600       60.00
   960x540       60.00
   800x600       70.00    65.00    60.00    56.00
   840x525       70.00    60.00
   700x525       70.00    60.00
   800x450       60.00
   640x512       60.00
   720x450       60.00
   700x450       60.00
   640x480       60.00
   684x384       60.00
   680x384       60.00
   640x400       60.00
   576x432       70.00    60.00
   640x360       60.00
   512x384       70.00    60.00
   512x288       60.00
   480x270       60.00
   400x300       60.00    56.00
   320x240       60.00

I have a couple of other linux systems where everything just works so I'm thinking this is a driver issue but I have no idea what to do about it.

Any ideas?

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

In the recovery terminal, or if you can connect remotely, try adding `nomodeset` to your grub configuration:

```
sudo sed -i "s|quiet splash|quiet nomodeset splash|g" /usr/share/grub/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

This will change the line in `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`

From...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset splash"
```

This instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead *until* X is loaded.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Just to confirm, my grub file is now:

GRUB_DEFAULT=0

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden

GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: That looks right. Since this didn't work, you can revert to the original using `sudo sed -i "s|quiet nomodeset splash|quiet splash|g" /usr/share/grub/default/grub`. Remember to execute `sudo update-grub` after making any changes to your grub configuration.

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. If you haven't already looked at this, perhaps it will help?... https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Thanks for trying. I think the answer is to move on from 18.04 as soon as I can. It's been a very painful experience (2 out of 3 upgrades to it  failed and resulted in unbootable systems, continuing problems with NFS, LAN drop-outs, desktop freezes etc. etc.) Wish I'd stayed with 14.04. That was a good vintage :-).

Answer (score 0):

Update: I wasn't able to get the display working in 18.04. I eventually upgraded to 20.04 (clean install) and although I was able to get a signal this time, the display was badly corrupted (looked like a line sync problem). The BIOS slash screen was always OK but the purple Ubuntu screen never displayed properly. I tried 3 different monitors and none of them worked although they all displayed differently.
I cured the problem by installing an old NVidia GPU and disabling the on-board graphics (it's an Intel Skylake).