# How to rotate a screen to portrait mode

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, xrandr, orientation

I've tried most of the solutions I've found so far still to no avail. I have a 29" widescreen Dell monitor running Ubuntu 18.04.4. First I went into display settings and attempted to switch to portrait mode, it logged me out, I logged back in, nothing changed. I tried landscape flipped and it worked just fine.

Next, I tried using various `xrandr` commands (see below)

**xrandr commands**

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate right
xrandr -o right
```

If needed I can get any output log, I just don't know which one's you all may need to see. I think the weirdest part of the problem is that landscape works in both ways, but portrait doesn't work in either direction. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution linked from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04) question but I'll paste here for easy access.

It's apparently a better solution to run X11 as root. The one-line fix is to add this to this to `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`:

`needs_root_rights = yes`

It's a one line fix in `/lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service`

```
Replace

[Service]

ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config

with

[Service]

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/share/gdm/generate-config
```