# Restart a Display-Port with the command line

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, displayport

Sorry if this has already been answered in some way before, but I was wondering if there was a way to restart a DisplayPort from the command line to put it simply. I've read some other similar questions before, but I couldn't figure out if they were what I needed.

The issue its self is that my laptop (running Intel Integrated Graphics) doesn't have HDMI, so I use a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter for my monitor. It seems to not recognize the adapter on startup, and continues to ignore it until I unplug it and plug it back in, but while that solution works, its repetitive, and I don't want to wear down the port.

I'm running Ubuntu-Mate 20.04.1 LTS, and if it helps my exact laptop is a HP EliteBook 8470p.

Comment: so the monitor does not show up in the display settings to choose from? to turn off an on? even after hitting the "Detect monitors" button?

Comment: @WU-TANG just checked now, the display settings were only showing my laptop monitor until i re-plugged it.

Comment: have you tried these? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Got busy with a bunch of stuff, but just tried those now that i had a chance. I tried the run X11 as root solution, tried running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` which didn't do anything, no drivers were found. Im already using lightdm aswell.