# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS won't detect second monitor

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, intel

If anyone could help me, I'm having this issue with my hdmi televisor. It is simple not detectable. I tried switching from gdr3 to lightdm and vice versa, but still not working.
In configuration menu, on monitor tab, it is not shown the monitor either, only a few options for my native display.

Comment: Have you looked at the discussion here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04