# Unmet dependencies: nvidia-kernel-common-460

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, multiple-monitors, dependencies

I was trying to solve an issue with my external monitor in Ubuntu 20.04 with my asus-rog

I tried the following solution, [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Now I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (<= 460.39-1) but 460.56-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Make sure that you don't have the focal-proposed Repo enabled in your Settings -> Software & Updates -> Developers Options.

Comment: Can you post what GPU is installed in your system? Different NVIDIA driver versions support different GPU series. You can do `lspci | grep VGA` in a terminal window.

Answer (score -2):

haha I just did exactly the same thing over here on my system messing around; was bored sitting here reading that the Vulkan drivers may perform better after watching a video comparing the Radeon RX 5700 XT's to the 3060 TI's and my mind started wandering off - probably from lack of sleep, plus all the nicotine and caffeine :) Anyway I had the 460 driver's up and running nicely but then started screwing around and after reading into all this stuff, Nvidia's website says to use the 430 driver for the 20 series cards?? Who knows, so then I sit here purge all the stuff I had working, put the 430 driver on and apparently it screwed up the configuration files... system kernel is still loading something off the 460 driver's, and yea.. now my computer is working but plasma's all screwed up, spitting out errors at me and games are running at like 13 FPS. Why do they gotta make this stuff so frustrating man? At least I know what's going on but hell if i know how to manually edit kernel configuration files. THAT's what got me to say to hell with WSL2 and just go 100% linux in the first place (I was watching that "Dave's garage guy" on youtube and trying to just put a straight linux kernel in WSL2 when I made a stupid typo that screwed everything up lmfao). "Aww shit, here we go again"

Comment: Try improving the answer after some good night's sleep (:

Comment: Ok, easiest way to fix this real fast after farting around is as follows: 1) Click on the Application Launcher icon (just like the start button in windows) 2) Go into System Settings 3) After you are in System Settings go into Driver Manager (should prompt you to type in your password) 4) Relaunch the Driver Manager if the button pops up again make sure you are root aka "sudo" 5) In the Software Sources box that pops up click on the Additional Drivers tab 6) Click on the 1st option "Using Nvidia Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary) 7) Hit ok and you should be done. :)

Comment: Probably works for nvidia-driver-460-server (proprietary) too.. but I'm not planning on hosting any servers anytime soon LOL