# Second monitor isn't available in display settings

Tags: display, settings

I just installed Ubuntu and connected a second monitor, but the display settings is not showing properly. The settings simply do not show the option for a second monitor.

[image: Display Settings]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which monitor are you trying to connect? Is the connector HDMI, VGI or USB C? Are you sure cable isn't faulty?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 21.04, the monitor is a samsung and the connector is HDMI, the same monitor works perfectly on other devices and it worked until yesterday with windows on this one i am using now.

Comment: Does your system has nvidia GPU by any chance?

Comment: Actually yes, i have an acer helios 300 with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/a/1099736 helps

Comment: i tried changing drivers and switching to lightdm but nothing seems to work

Comment: Did you try purging nvidia drivers? Does `xrandr --query` detect monitor?