# HDMI port on Samsung Galaxy Book2 360 doesn't work with Ubuntu 22

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, samsung

I purchased a Samsung Galaxy Book 2 360 and dual installed Ubuntu 22 alongside Windows 11.  Installation went without a hitch, and literally the laptop worked almost perfectly after the installation.  However, the HDMI port doesn't output anything.  I have an external monitor that works just fine with Windows.  The monitor is auto-detected by Windows but I can't get it to work with Ubuntu.  There are function switches on the top row of the keyboard that Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize, including one to swap video output to the HDMI port.
Any guidance on enabling the HDMI port on a Samsung Galaxy Book2 360 running Ubuntu 22 is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this on Lenovo ThinkPad as well. Upgraded from Ubuntu 20 to 22 and external monitor started bugging out. First the second display image turned all green, which I tried to fix by purging and reinstalling latest NVidia drivers and resorting back to X.Org Nouveau driver after a while (Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers). After one of the reboots the HDMI output stopped working altogether.

What I noticed had happened in the end, was that the Secure Boot option from BIOS had turned on and needed to be switched back off in order to make the second monitor behave normally. Try to locate that setting and see if it helps.

If unlucky, you can try other fixes found from this thread: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-my-second-hdmi-display/75076

A lot of suggestions in this old thread as well: [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Nothing worked, but I will keep looking for answers.  Thanks!