# HDMI doesn't work on Thinkpad T16 with Ubuntu 22.10/22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi, thinkpad, 22.10

I have a brand new laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad T16 Gen 1) with Ubuntu 22.10 installed (I had 22.04 and thought that upgrade of the system + kernel would solve it) and so far I haven't been able to get HDMI to work. If I use USB-C to HDMI reduction monitor works fine, but when directly plugging into HDMI port it's not showing up (I tried several monitors which I know work)

When I leave the HDMI connected and reboot I can see the Lenovo logo, so I know the HDMI is not broken. It stops working right after the boot screen.

I tried several solutions (most was summarized in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)), but nothing worked so far.

In Software updates -> additional drivers I see `No additional drivers available`.

I already tried

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

But that didn't work.

What might be relevant:

```
uname -a                                                                                 
Linux 0101-03-016-001 5.19.0-29-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 4 12:14:09 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
sudo lshw -short
H/W path        Device          Class          Description
==========================================================
                                system         21BV0021CK (LENOVO_MT_21BV_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad T16 Gen 1)
/0                              bus            21BV0021CK
/0/1                            memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/1/0                          memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0,3 ns)
/0/1/1                          memory         [empty]
/0/1/2                          memory         [empty]
/0/1/3                          memory         [empty]
/0/1/4                          memory         [empty]
/0/1/5                          memory         [empty]
/0/1/6                          memory         [empty]
/0/1/7                          memory         [empty]
/0/12                           memory         192KiB L1 cache
/0/13                           memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/14                           memory         5MiB L2 cache
/0/15                           memory         18MiB L3 cache
/0/16                           memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/17                           memory         512KiB L1 cache
/0/18                           memory         4MiB L2 cache
/0/19                           memory         18MiB L3 cache
/0/1a                           processor      12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1260P
/0/1b                           memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/100                          bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/2        /dev/fb0        display        Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/4                        generic        Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Partici
/0/100/6                        bridge         12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0
/0/100/6/0      /dev/nvme0      storage        SKHynix_HFS512GDE9X081N
/0/100/6/0/0    hwmon3          disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/2    /dev/ng0n1      disk           NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/1    /dev/nvme0n1    disk           512GB NVMe disk
/0/100/6/0/1/1  /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/6/0/1/2  /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         476GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/7                        bridge         Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0
/0/100/7.2                      bridge         Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2
/0/100/a                        generic        Platform Monitoring Technology
/0/100/d                        bus            Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
/0/100/d/0      usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/d/1      usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/d.2                      bus            Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0
/0/100/d.3                      bus            Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1
/0/100/14                       bus            Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0     usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1   input10         input          Lenovo USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/3                   generic        Generic USB device
/0/100/14/0/4   input15         multimedia     Integrated Camera: Integrated I
/0/100/14/0/8                   generic        EMV Smartcard Reader
/0/100/14/0/a                   communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/1     usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                     memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3     wlp0s20f3       network        Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
/0/100/15                       bus            Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/16                       communication  Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller
/0/100/1f                       bridge         Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f/0                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/2                     generic        PnP device LEN0071
/0/100/1f/3                     generic        PnP device LEN030b
/0/100/1f/4                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/5                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/6                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/7                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/8                     system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/100/1f.3     card0           multimedia     Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1f.4                     bus            Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller
/0/100/1f.5                     bus            Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller
/0/100/1f.6     enp0s31f6       network        Ethernet Connection (16) I219-V
/1                              power          5B10W51869
/2              input0          input          Sleep Button
/3              input1          input          Lid Switch
/4              input13         input          Intel HID events
/5              input14         input          ThinkPad Extra Buttons
/6              input17         input          SYNA801A:00 06CB:CEC6 Mouse
/7              input18         input          SYNA801A:00 06CB:CEC6 Touchpad
/8              input2          input          Power Button
/9              input20         input          Video Bus
/a              input21         input          sof-hda-dsp Mic
/b              input22         input          sof-hda-dsp Headphone
/c              input23         input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/d              input24         input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
/e              input25         input          sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
/f              input26         input          M720 Triathlon Keyboard
/10             input27         input          M720 Triathlon Mouse
/11             input3          input          AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/12             input5          input          TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint
```

```
xrandr                                                                                  
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     60.00 +  60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Do you have any ideas how to get it to work? Thanks

Comment: @guiverc it was a typo, 22.04+22.10 is correct

Answer (score 1):

After couple of days of struggle I finally managed to resolve it. My search led me here:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Thinkpad-T14-Gen-3-has-no-available-HDMI-ports-under-Linux/m-p/5147202?page=1

I checked my BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and found out to be 1.01.
So in the end I updated my BIOS to current version and then it started working :)

They even mention this bugfix in the [info txt file](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n3bul07w.txt).

```
<1.27>
 UEFI: 1.27 / ECP: 1.12 
- (Fix) Fixd HDMI port is useless in Linux OS.
```

You'll find available BIOS updates on this page:
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds557163-bios-update-utility-bootable-cd-for-windows-11-10-64-bit-thinkpad-t14-gen-3-p14s-gen-3-t16-gen-1-p16s-gen-1

How to update your BIOS: https://support.lenovo.com/cz/en/solutions/ht510810

Comment: Thanks for coming back and writing this thorough answer.